# x-axis label as text not number

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have found ways to do this but they seem to work only in the case when there is only one input for every output.

I have a scatter plot and I'd like to use the X values (which are string values) as the x-axis values rather than numbers.

As an example data set:

```
cookie1, 2
cookie1, 3
cookie1, 4
cookie2, 2
cookie2, 4
cookie2, 4
```

So I would like the x axis to read cookie1, cookie2, etc...while the y axis maintains the rest of the scatter plot for the values (in this case 2-4).

Right now, as it plots out, instead of cookie1, or cookie2 in the x-axis it reads 1,2,3,etc...

I have tried making a vector of values housing cookie1, cookie2, etc individually, but that blows up in my face too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set `xaxt='n'` in your `plot` call and then call `axis(1, ...)` with the relevant positions and labels for x-axis ticks.

Comment: I seemed to finally have gotten that to work. I've found that answer 100 times on here -- but I had been using axis=FALSE instead and tried the separate plots prior...Feel like an idiot, but glad to have this working how I want now. THANKS!!

Answer (score 3):

You can set the x-axis labels to null and then add the labels from the data with `axis`.

```
d <- read.table(text = 'cookie1, 2
 cookie1, 3
 cookie1, 4
 cookie2, 2
 cookie2, 4
 cookie2, 4', sep = ',')

> plot(d$V2, xaxt = 'n', pch = 19)
> axis(1, at = seq(nrow(d)), labels = d$V1)
```

[image]